# DDS textures in a GLB file

Tags: export, gltf

I have recently discovered that the gltf exporter from Blender is automatically converting all of the texture data from whatever the original format is to either jpg or png (in my case it is always png).

My textures inside my blend file are in the DDS format, how can I produce a glb file with DDS textured from the gltf exporter of Blender ?

If it is not possible, are there any other solutions ?

Regards.

Comment: There's no easy way. glTF only supports PNG/JPG. There's an extension for DDS, but it isn't widely supported.

Comment: The recommended path to use GPU-compressed textures is to use the more modern [KTX2](https://www.khronos.org/ktx/) not proprietary old DDS.  But sadly, the Blender side of this is not built (...yet?), so for now, one must resort to post-processing the exported glTF with a tool such as [gltf-transform](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/).